# Подскажите как использовать колбек в useState хуке?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

вот есть такой код и я не понимаю как переписать его на функциональный компонент, как использовать колбек в useState хуке?

```
const [fieldError, setFieldError] = useState({})

this.setState((state: any) => {
                        return {
                          ...state,
                          fieldError: {},
                        };
                      },
                      () => {
                        errs?.inner?.forEach((err: any) => {
                          this.setState((state: any) => {
                            return {
                              ...state,
                              fieldError: {
                                ...state.fieldError,
                                [index]: {
                                  ...state.fieldError[index],
                                  [err.path]: err.message,
                                },
                              },
                            };
                          });
                        });
                      },
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

То что в колбеке можно вынести в useEffect:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (errs) ...
}, [errs]);
```

или использовать что то вроде [такого](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback) useStateWithCallback
работает как useState вторым параметром принимает колбек